# Confusion in ServiceDesk Notifications

Tags: jira

**Confusion in ServiceDesk Notifications :**
I implemented the new service desk project with it's own notification scheme. For the event, 'Issue Created', for example, i added a notification for the reporter to get an email, and then added a group of administrators to be notified as well. Only the reporter gets the notification. We tested this for several event types and see that only the first notification item works, and any subsequent notification item set for the same event do not get an alert.

How can all items receive the same email?

Comment: it's been awhile, but I remember adding JIRA automation rule that basically notified "admins" whenever a certain issue was created. 
https://support.atlassian.com/jira-service-desk-cloud/docs/create-a-custom-automation-rule/